# React native: TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...data.map...') on building a simple app

Tags: reactjs, react-native

So, I was building a simple mobile application on react native. On my history page,
I built a table using the react-native-table-component library, and on pressing the column of the table, it would redirect the user to a page called 'test'.

But whenever I try to run the app, it always shows "TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...data.map...')"

Can anybody please help?
I have uploaded the code for reference.

HistoryScreen code:

```
 import *as React from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet, Button} from 'react-native';
import {Table, Row, Rows} from 'react-native-table-component';
import { useState } from 'react/cjs/react.development';
import { NavigationContainer, TabActions} from '@react-navigation/native';
import test from './test';
import HomeScreen from './HomeScreen';


const tableData={
    tableHead: ['Incident Report'],
    tableData: [
         ['Incident#1'],
         ['Incident#2'],
    ],
};
const styles=StyleSheet.create({
    container: {flex: 1, padding: 10, justifyContent:'center', backgroundColor:'#fff'},
    head: { height: 44, backgroundColor: 'darkblue' },
    headText: { fontSize: 20, fontWeight: 'bold' , textAlign: 'center', color: 'white' },
    text: { margin: 6, fontSize: 16, fontWeight: 'bold' , textAlign: 'center' },
});
export default function HistoryScreen({navigation}){
    const [data, setData] = useState(tableData);

    return(
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Table borderStyle={{borderWidth: 4,borderColor: 'teal'}}>
                <Rows onPress={()=> navigation.navigate('HomeScreen')} data={data.tableHead} style={styles.head} textStyle={styles.headText}/> 
                <Rows data={data.tableData} textStyle={styles.text}/>
             </Table>
        </View>
    );
}
```

homepage code

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {View, Text} from 'react-native';

export default function test(){
    return(
        <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#fff',  alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
              <Text
                  style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#fff', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}> test </Text>
        </View>
    );
}

import * as React from 'react';
import {View, Text} from 'react-native';

export default function HomeScreen( {navigation} ){
    return(
        <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#fff',  alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
            <Text
                onPress={()=> alert('This is the "Home" Screen')}
                style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#fff', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}> test test</Text>
        </View>
    );
}
```

Comment: I think the problem would be on your `HomeScreen` file, but since you didn't post it, I can't say for sure. Please share your `HomeScreen` code too

Comment: Thanks for informing, I added HomeScreen code

Comment: sorry my bad. It wasn't in `HomeScreen`. Is there anywhere else where you use `Row` or have any props called `data` in your codes? Do you mind sharing the screenshot of the error?

Comment: Can you try running server with `--reset-cache`? like `npm start -- --reset-cache`

Comment: Also your `import { useState } from 'react/cjs/react.development'` should be `import { useState } from 'react'`

Comment: Tried both of your methods @OrkhanAlikhanov, still not working :CC

Comment: @jted95 Nope.. dont have any other row or data in my code

Comment: @AouxWoux, I think I found the problem. I'll post it in the answer

Answer (score 1):

The problem most likely comes from your `HistoryScreen` code. This is the part where the error come from.

```js
<Rows onPress={()=> navigation.navigate('HomeScreen')} data={data.tableHead} style={styles.head} textStyle={styles.headText}/>
```

If you see carefully in your import there are two different components called `Row` and `Rows`. From what I saw in the docs, it seems to take two different data shape. `Row` takes an `array` and `Rows` takes an `array` within `array`.

This is what your code supposed to look like:

```js
...
        <Table borderStyle={{ borderWidth: 4, borderColor: 'teal' }}>
          <Row
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate('HomeScreen')}
            data={data.tableHead}
            style={styles.head}
            textStyle={styles.headText}
          />
          <Rows data={data.tableData} textStyle={styles.text} />
        </Table>
...
```